# vba autofilter for blank and all dates this year

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I have been trying to use VBA to filter a particular column for any dates in current year (dynamic) PLUS any blank cells.

This is what I have:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", "HZ" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=60, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=xlFilterThisYear, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

Criteria1 filters for blanks and criteria2 dynamically filters for this year.

When used seperately, they both work, but when I want them both to work together, only the firast criteria works. BTW, I have tried xlAnd and xlOr just in case!!

When I recorded the macro to do this, I had the following statement recorded:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", "HZ" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=60, Criteria1:=Array("="), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "3/2/2018").
```

This works, but as you can see, there is a hard date in there, which I would need to change every week, so I would like a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can use this code to provide the dynamic filter value to `Autofilter`:

```
Dim startDate As Long,
Dim enddate As Long
startDate = Range("B1")
Enddate = Range("B2")
Range("D2:D123").AutoFilter Field:=1,
Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, _ Operator:=xlAnd, _ Criteria2:="<=" &
Enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

This will hide all dates before the first of the year and empty cells in column 60. If you want to hide the dates in the current year change the "<" to ">". To undo hiddne rows use this code `Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, i As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet

lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 60).End(xlUp).row

Dim CurYr As Double
CurYr = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)

    For i = 1 To lRow
        If Cells(i, 60) < CurYr Or Cells(i, 60) = "" Then
        Rows(i).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you GMalc - i had to tweak your code a bit to get the blanks to remain rather than be filtered out, but you have solved my problem: If Cells(i, 60) <> "" And Cells(i, 60) < CurYr Then